# How to override a variable from another class in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

Im working on a PyQt5 app:

I have two classes (mainWindow & devicePanel).
Got some buttons (qbtn) in mainWindow, which makes devicePanel to appear when they are clicked.
My problem is that I need to override some variables in devicePanel class on 'qbtn' click event.

So:

When mainWindow.qbtn is pressed, it should make devicePanel appear and override some of its variables (l_ip, l_st, etc).

**I CANNOT make mainWindow parent of devicePanel, please don't suggest it, it won't solve my problem.**

Here is my code:

```
class mainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(1280, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test window')
        self.genBtns()
        self.show()


    def genBtns(self):

        devices = []
        devices.append(['A', 21, 1, 'W', '2', 'n/a'])
        devices.append(['A', 22, 2, 'O', '0', 'n/a'])
        devices.append(['A', 31, 3, 'W', '32', '11'])

        for a in range (0, int(len(devices))):
            self.addButton(devices[a][0], devices[a][1], devices[a][2],  devices[a][3],  devices[a][4],  devices[a][5])


    def addButton(self, z, x, y, status, bp, cp):

        qbtn = QPushButton(str(x), self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.buttonClicked(z, x, y, status, bp, cp))    # BUTTON CLICK EVENT
        qbtn.resize(70, 70)
        qbtn.move(20, 20)
        if (status == 'O'):
            qbtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        elif (status == 'W'):
            qbtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        else:
            qbtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray")    


    def buttonClicked(self, z, x, y, status, bp, cp): # BUTTON CLICK METHOD

        self.dp = devicePanel()
        self.dp.initUI()
        self.dp.l_ip = '192.168.0.134'
        self.dp.show()


class devicePanel(QWidget):

    l_ip = '192.168.0.135'    #NEED TO CHANGE THESE VALUES!
    l_st = 'active'
    l_bp = '10'
    l_cp = '2'
    l_bc = '90'
    l_cc = '150'
    l_sc = '240'


    def __init__(self):

        super(devicePanel, self).__init__(None)
        self.addDPbtns()
        self.initUI()
```

Comment: maybe define class so you could do `devicePanel('192.168.0.134', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your class so it accepts arguments to set those values.  In this example, the `l_xx` class variables just become the defaults.  The `self.xx` variables are the real variables.  They will be set to whatever you pass in, or if you don't pass anything in, they become defaults.

```
class devicePanel(QWidget):

    l_ip = '192.168.0.135'    #NEED TO CHANGE THESE VALUES!
    l_st = 'active'
    l_bp = '10'
    l_cp = '2'
    l_bc = '90'
    l_cc = '150'
    l_sc = '240'

    def __init__(ip=None, st=None, bp=None, cp=None, bc=None, cc=None, sc=None):
        super(devicePanel, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip or self.l_ip
        self.st = st or self.l_st
        self.bp = bp or self.l_bp
        self.cp = cp or self.l_cp
        self.bc = bc or self.l_bc
        self.cc = cc or self.l_cc
```

Then instantiate it like ths

```
def buttonClicked(self, z, x, y, status, bp, cp): # BUTTON CLICK METHOD

    ip = '192.168.0.134'
    self.dp = devicePanel(ip=ip, bp=bp, cp=cp, st=status)
    self.dp.initUI()
    self.dp.show()
```

Comment: Thanks man! Your solution works perfectly. I had to change a few things in my original code (it is not excatly the same as the one I posted because I made a lot of changes since I posted the question), so it took me some time, to figure out the logic, but it works. Simple and elegant. Thank once again!